# How to provide car resources in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm struggling with android car mode. I'm trying to create simple app that will use different layouts for normal mode and for car mode.

Android provides a method UiModeManager.enableCarMode which according to documentation should force the phone to car mode. Documentation also states that there can be resources with -car suffix. (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Bringing this together, I would expect, that the framework will use different resources when car mode is enabled and different when it is disabled.

However I've made a very simple prototype and it is not working. I have only one activity with layout activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0bbbff">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/car_mode"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

TextView has a text attribute @string/car_mode which is defined in res\values\strings.xml and also in res\values-car\strings.xml.

When I'm switching car mode on and off with UiModeManager, the text doesn't change.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the "solution". Apparently -car suffix only works with -land suffix.

When my folder is values-land-car instead of values-car the layout looks as it should. Of course there is no notion in documentation that car mode works only in landscape, good work guys.